# vb.net How to Fire Click Event Dynamically

Tags: vb.net, events, dynamic, click, devexpress

I'm trying to fire a click-event by clicking on another control 
using this following code:

```
Private Sub GroupControl4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupControl4.Click
    For Each c As Control In XtraTabControl1.Controls
        For Each cs As Control In DirectCast(c, DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage).Controls
            If cs.Tag = sender.Tag Then
                cs.PerformClick()
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

And I got this error:

> "'PerformClick' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"

I also tried to DirectCast, which I didn't helper either.

Comment: Why not put the code in a sub and call it from the click event or wherever else you need to?  Otherwise the error means what it says: Click is an event on some but not all controls, like the `Control` class.  Cast it to whatever type you are trying to click - or filter the controls loop.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Don't you use Intellisense? This should be underlined in your debugger. This is a compiler error right? Has to be.

Comment: the code must be Dynamically, and is a Compiler error, what is the solution?

Comment: It is a member of Button.  So DirectCast(cs, Button).PerformClick() would be sensible.

Comment: the "cs" it's not a Button, and I can't cast to a Button, it's a "GroupControl"

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

I'm creating a new Function

```
    Private Sub FireEvent(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal EventName As String)
    Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
    Dim EventP As PropertyInfo = Nothing
    Dim CtrlS As Object = ctrl.[GetType]
    Dim FoundEvents As Boolean = False
    While FoundEvents = False
        EventP = CtrlS.GetProperty("Events", flags)
        If EventP Is Nothing Then
            CtrlS = CtrlS.BaseType
        Else
            FoundEvents = True
        End If
    End While

    Dim EventF As FieldInfo = Nothing
    CtrlS = ctrl.[GetType]
    Dim FoundField As Boolean = False
    While FoundField = False
        EventF = CtrlS.GetField(EventName, flags)
        If EventF Is Nothing Then
            CtrlS = CtrlS.BaseType
        Else
            FoundField = True
        End If
    End While


    If Not EventP Is Nothing Then
        Dim eventH = DirectCast(EventP.GetValue(ctrl, Nothing), EventHandlerList)
        Dim eventFIeld As Object = EventF.GetValue(Nothing)
        Dim handlers As [Delegate] = eventH(eventFIeld)
        For Each handler As [Delegate] In handlers.GetInvocationList()
            handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, New Object() {ctrl, New EventArgs})
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

and this code work excellent

```
Private Sub GroupControl4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupControl4.Click, GroupControl5.Click
    For Each c As Control In XtraTabControl1.Controls
        For Each cs As Control In DirectCast(c, DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage).Controls
            If cs.Tag = sender.Tag Then
                FireEvent(cs, "EventClick")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you re-think your implementation. Just because it works is not a good thing. Something is clearly wrong with what you're doing with the rest of the code. Will you understand this code after being away from it for 6 months.

Comment: hi Michael, if you have a better solution, I'm happy to here about this. the Cs its a "GroupControl", and I need raiseEvent Click for this control dynamically by outer control by the condition of the "Tag" , very thanks

Comment: That would require seeing more of your implementation. Maybe you should post a much larger chunk of code to the code review site so we can help you design it better....https://codereview.stackexchange.com/